# Can I determine which are the "new" tweets on my Twitter feed?

Tags: twitter

When I read my Twitter feed, I can't tell what's new and what is old at a glance. I have to read things one by one.

With email, one can simply delete old emails or clear them or mark them as read. Is there some kind of similar mechanism with Twitter?

Comment: Nope. At least, not without an external script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done within the standard interface of Twitter. But any worthwhile Twitter client will probably have such a feature. For example, Tweetdeck -- which is now owned by Twitter and uses Twitter login. https://tweetdeck.twitter.com/

At the top of a Tweetdeck column, click "Settings" icon, then click "Clear" to remove all tweets. Next time, it will show only the new ones.

[image: column]